# Stacked Multi Bar Graph in Qlikview

Tags: qlikview

Background Knowledge on Application:

1. In Simulation many users can be involved but a few (typically 2 to 3) will do actually the Simulation.
2. A Simulation has Phases, A Phase has Actions and these can be performed by users in the process of Simulation.
3. A set of Users will do a Simulation and another set of Users will observe that process.
4. Once the Simulation process is done, the users who are observing the simulation will evaluate the users who did actually. And at the same time the faculty will also evaluate the users (who did the simulation)

I have implemented a dashboard/graph to represent the complete above scenario, by directly showing graph based on simulation id and user in the beginning. If we select any particular simulation then the graph changes o next level i.e based on users, who did that simulation actually (Here the dimension is user name). Then if we select any user then it will dig down to next level i.e based on the phases (here the dimension is phase), again if we select the phase then it will change, based on the actions (here dimension is the action).

This part id done and attached the screenshot and .qvw file as well.

Now the main task here is, I need to compare student given marks with faculty given marks (both are in different tables, i.e studentscore & facultyscore), in the same graph using stacked multi bar graph at user level, phase level, action level.

Attached the screenshot for reference (please see in the Reference sheet).

May be some of the dimensions or expression are wrong, or I am not sure actually.

I am able to do with only one level, but not in these levels (level by level, like, based on users, based on phases, and based on actions)

I really tried in many ways, but it is not working as expected.

You can download the attachments here
https://slack-files.com/T02FXUAB9-F308KT8PQ-c53db69bbb

https://slack-files.com/T02FXUAB9-F2YSTAW72-bba2433d6f

Comment: One last piece of info please. Can you draw a picture of the graph you are expecting from this data?

Comment: @ The Budac: Please find the link for the document here https://slack-files.com/T02FXUAB9-F2ZFGQZME-4ec1868ba8